# Overloaded Output Operator Gives Hexadecimal Numbers Instead of String

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a this Tree Class:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef HUFF_TREE_H
#define HUFF_TREE_H

class HuffTree{
    public:
        HuffTree();
        HuffTree(char data, float frequency);
        ~HuffTree();
        HuffTree& operator = (const HuffTree& tree);
        int getNumberNodes();
        float getFrequency();
        void merge(HuffTree *tree);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const HuffTree &tree);

    private:
        struct node{
            char data;
            float frequency;
            node* left;
            node* right;
        };
        node* head;
        int number_nodes;
        float avg_code_length;
        void destroy(node* &head);
        void copyTree(node* &t1, node* t2);
};

#endif
```

Here is the code for the overloaded output operator:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const HuffTree &tree){
    out << "testing";
    return out;
}
```

In my main function, I call function as follows:

```
HuffTree* tree;
cout << tree;
```

From what I have read, this should work, but I am getting hexadecimal numbers printed to the screen.  The above example prints out "0x1dcc2b0".  The same thing happens if I pass it a file handle.  I think I just need a fresh pair of eyes here, can anyone see my problem?

Comment: Please show the definition of `tree`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since tree is a pointer, you're outputting a pointer.

Instead, you want to do this:

```
cout << *tree
```

Comment: And all of a sudden it makes sense... I'm programming in Linux, and im using Geany to edit my code.  I tried that before, but it spit all sorts of errors out at me so I thought I couldn't do that for some reason.  Just ran Make outside of Geany and it compiled and ran perfectly.  Thanks mate!